# Fetch My Own Alexa Shopping list into a Bootstrap table

Tags: ajax, list, amazon-web-services, api, alexa-skills-kit

Did research on SOW & Alexa Documentation but iam a bit overwhelmed.

What i wanted to do is **access** my own alexa shopping list and list the items in a simple **bootstrap table**.
So i can style it my way and have it ready for printing.

My Idea was using ajax and then look how the data is delivered and then style it accordingly.
Is Ajax the right way to do it or where could i research to finally get my dream Idea to work.

```
function fetchAlexaList() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("shoppinglist").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.amazonalexa.com/myshoppinglist", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

I found docs on how to create my own skill and then you get tokkens and so on but i basically only want to access my own list, hope this is possible without creating a custom alexa skill. didnt found the right api address for my own shopping list tho.
Thx for being a awesome community welcoming newcomers **<3**

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the skill messaging API. You'll need to include a Login with Amazon authorization flow in your web site to get the token.

Start here (
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/access-the-alexa-shopping-and-to-do-lists.html#out-of-session-interaction) to find out where to get the client ID and client secret needed to implement the authorization flow and then follow down the page for more on implementing it and then querying the API for your list.

Comment: thank you so much that helps out a ton!
gonna look at it tomorrow :)

since the print out function inside the alexa app looks horrible i just want to style it in a nice bootstrap list to get myself a nice shopping list and be proud ofmyself that i did coded it after 4 months of learning basic web technologys :D :D